# How should I declare a has-a dependency via OSGi declarative services?

Tags: java, osgi, declarative-services

My OSGi application uses a whiteboard pattern to register listeners for specific state changes. I use org.apache.felix.scr.annotations to declare my services and components instead of hand-coding the declarative XML. The easiest way to register my component as a ChangeListener is like so:

```
@Component(name="...")
@Service
public class MyComponent implements ChangeListener {
    @Override public void changeOccurred(...) {
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

That's an is-a relationship and it exposes my component to anyone who asks for it. Instead, I want a has-a relationship to register my ChangeListener via an inner class. But the following is VERY ugly by comparison to the above.

```
@Component(name="...")
public class MyComponent {
    private ServiceRegistration registration;

    protected final void activate(final ComponentContext context) {
        registration = context.getBundleContext()
               .registerService(ChangeListener.class.getName(),
        new ChangeListener() {
            @Override public void changeOccurred(...) {
                // ...
            }
        }, null);
    }
    protected final void deactivate(final ComponentContext context) {
        registration.unregister();
    }
    // ...
}
```

Is there a better way to implement the contained listener that's not so verbose but which still achieves the information hiding of an inner class?

Comment: There is no support for this in Declarative Services. However I don't really see what's wrong with the first example... seems nice and clean to me. Can you explain your motivation a little more?

Comment: @Neil Bartlett - my component has multiple other public methods and interfaces that I don't want exposed to anyone who asks for a ChangeListener. It's not that big a deal I guess, but I wanted to follow the pattern of exposing a minimum surface when injecting callbacks. It's a very common pattern in Swing.

Comment: Oh, I should have added this detail: the "MyComponent" class has several @Reference annotations, too. I omitted them for brevity. The point is that MyComponent itself is not a service, but is a user of services. The only service-like element of MyComponent is the listener.

Comment: Well the component class should be in a private package, so another bundle would not have visibility of any methods other than those on the `ChangeListener` interface (unless they use reflection I suppose). Anyway, I kind of see your point, but the fact remains that DS doesn't support the pattern you want.

Comment: Thanks Neil, you rock. And thank you for the OSGi in Practice draft book. It was the first book I read when I started learning about OSGi a year ago.